# Connecting Sensor via UART to Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, uart, rfid

I have the following [RFID sensor](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?mpart=113020002&v=1597) that communicates via UART. I got the pins properly connected (RX - TX and TX - RX, PWR - 5V and ground to ground).

I am trying to read my corporate badge which runs at 125 khz with the RFID sensor. I have tried using the following code, to read my badge when I hover it around the sensor. But it simply prints `b''` on the screen, so is not reading the badge. I needed advice on what I should try to do to read the badge or what changes I can make in the software?

```
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=9600, timeout=3.0)

while True:
    rcv = port.read(10)
    print(rcv)
```

Comment: Did the sensor come with a test card? It doesn't look like it, but mine did so maybe..

Comment: Mine did not come with a test card. Did you buy it from same location as me above?

Comment: no, mine is not the same, but it would have been helpful for the seller to include one that is known to work-- would at least help narrow down what is the issue here.

Comment: Did you use the same software as me? Were there any specific configurations that needed to be made on the pi?

Comment: What Pi are you using? On the newer versions (>=3) you should use `/dev/serial0` or `/dev/serial1` for the device path. Did you run `raspi-config` to initiate the serial interface? Just some random ideas; not quite sure, what causes the problem

Comment: It is a raspberry pi 3 B+. I tried /dev/serial0 and still nothing. I did initiate serial to be turned on in raspi-config.

Comment: I’d expect the Pi serial ports to work off 3.3V - you need to be very careful not to exceed 3.3V into them from your device. Does it definitely need 5V? Have you checked that RX<>TX and TX<>RX is correct? With 9600 baud if you put a red LED in series with a 1k resistor from 3.3v to whichever the ‘output’ pin of the card reader is, you might see a flash when it transmits? Do the same on the ‘output from the Pi with a terminal program to send some data, that is working. With the RFID reader disconnected loop the pi rx-tx and use that terminal program to confirm the serial port is working?

Comment: But this is all off-topic for StackOverflow :-o

Comment: This tutorial seems to cover it pretty well... https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-serial/